# python - Store the elements of a string into a list

Tags: python, list

I have a string with elements one below the other

For Ex:

print res ( where res is the result of a regular expression match )

> abc

> xyz

But i want to create a list with these elements,

final output: `lst = ['abc','xyz']`

I tried the below code, but its not working. Any help would be appreciated

```
lst = []

res = ""

with open(filename, "rt") as myfile:
    
    for line in myfile:

        if pattern.search(line) != None: 

            res = [sub[ : -2] for sub in line.split(' ')[6:len(line)-1]]  
 
            print res[0]    
            
            for h in res:

                print lst.append(h)
```

Comment: if you give no detailed context to you problem, people won't be able to answer you question and may downvote your question. Try to give more context to your problem and ask specific questions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your original file really looks like but this is the easy way via `split()` on newlines.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()
    data = s.split('\n')
    print(data)
```